# Adding current filename to a Vim shortcut

Tags: vim

I am new to Vim and trying to add a new shortcut. I was wondering how I can put current file's path to the command dynamically. So that every time I use that shortcut, my command will executed with correct filepath in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is `expand("%")`. It will return the file you are currently editing. If you use `expand("%:p")` you will get the full path of that file. So say you would want to have a shortcut to print your current file in the command bar and you wanted it mapped to F5. Then you would add the following in your `.vimrc`:

```
map <F5> :echo expand("%:p")<CR>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
nnoremap <expr> <leader>cd (expand("%:p:h") !~ '^/tmp') ? ":lcd %:p:h\<CR>:echo expand(\"%:p:h\")\<CR>" : "echo \"foo\"\<CR>"
```

I have this line in my .vimrc to what you want.  My leader is ',' so when I type ,cd it changes the local directory to that of the current file.

Comment: I am really new to vim, and the thing you have written doesn't make any sense to me as it is. Can you explain this a little bit newbie friendly?

Comment: @yasar11732: `he filename-modifiers` and `he :_%`

Comment: @evan: that could be as simple as `nmap <leader>cd :cd %:h`